# Why I can't get arguments length with default value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function like

```
function f(a=1, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
}
console.log(f.length);
```

and I want to get the length of f like `f.length` , but what I get is **0** not **2**. But when I change the `a` to normal formal parameter without default value, the result of `f.length` is **2** , why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which is the expected behavior, check [MDN docs of `Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> **length is a property of a function object, and indicates how many arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters. This number excludes the rest parameter and only includes parameters before the first one with a default value**. By contrast, arguments.length is local to a function and provides the number of arguments actually passed to the function.

Comment: oh, thank you so much! But how can I get the length out of the function in this case?

Answer (score 2):

As said in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length/) ,

> Function.length includes parameters before the first one with a
> default value.

In your example function, first argument itself has a default value of `1`, thus `Function.length` doesn't include any arguments that you supply after `a` .

Hence it gives you value `0`.

To make things more clearer consider following snippets :

```js
//no arguments with default value
function f(a, b) {
  console.log('hello');
}
console.log('No of arguments ' + f.length);
```

Output will be 2

```js
//second argument has defualt value. Thus only argument a that is before the 
//argument having default value is included by Function.length
function f(a, b=1) {
  console.log('hello');
}
console.log(f.length);
```

Output will be 1

```js
//second argument has defualt value .
//but only arguments before the argument having default value are included
//thus b and c are excluded
function f(a, b=2, c) {
  console.log('hello');
}
console.log(f.length);
```

output will be 1